# Is there a lipsum-like package for metadata?

Tags: packages, package-writing

I know about the `lipsum`, `blindtext` and `kantlipsum` packages.  What I would need is a variant creating dummy metadata: author name/affiliation, title, thanks etc.  Does anyone know of anything like this?  (Paragraphs provided by `lipsum` or `kantlipsum` are way too long, it seems from a glance at the source that `blindtext` has a similar problem.)

And a bonus would be fake jpgs with author photos, for testing journal styles with author picture & bio at the end;).

If the answer is no (which is quite probable), I might consider adding something like this to `kantlipsum`.  What do you think, egreg?

Side note: if anyone knows what tags should accompany this question, please edit them.  Does it make sense to have a "dummy-text" tag?

Comment: Packages such as `blindtext`, `lipsum` and `kantlipsum` want to be as class independent as possible. What class   a `\metadata` command should be tailored to? For instance, `article` wants `\thanks` inside the `\author` field, `amsart` outside.

Comment: Well, but you might have commands like `\fakeauthor`, generating a fake name, with an optional argument, which might be an index from a table with, say, 20 names (just like with `[kant]lipsum`).  Then one might say, eg, `\author{\fakeauthor[8]}`.

Comment: Also the syntax for authors is quite different in the various classes, unfortunately.

Comment: That's true.  Another solution might be for such a package to detect the class and act accordingly in a few "popular" classes (say, standard LaTeX, AMS, memoir, koma, beamer) and fall back to commands like I suggested in other cases.

Comment: I really like this idea! Why not make it an independent package that can be used in addition to one of the existing dummy text packages? While I've never written a serious package, it shouldn't be too hard to produce the information in a way appropriate for the document class in use? That'd be one configuration for `article`, `report`, and `book`; another one for the KOMA-Script classes (I suppose), and perhaps some more for other classes.

Comment: @doncherry: thank you!  You are probably right that it should be a separate package.  Definitely, it is not too difficult - it is just a question of spending a few hours putting this code together.  I hope I'll have another train trip within a few weeks, I could try to do it then.  I was just curious whether there already is such an attempt.

Comment: `Paragraphs[...]are way too long` How long should the paragraphs be? Did you try blindtext with option `pangram` and `\blindtext[1]` or `\Blindtext[10][1]` (10 paragraphs with 1 sentence). The pangram texts are quiet short. Don't forget to load babel (`\usepackage[english]{babel}`)

Comment: @knut: for my purpose, I'd need (say) 2-6-word chunks of text.  (As I wrote, I didn't actually test `blindtext`.)

Comment: With pangram option you get 6-9 words - a bit more you need. If you are interested I could post an example to change the texts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I guess it's quite easy, don't waste your time!  Still, this is not exactly what I want: fake names, emails, addresses etc.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how a `lipsum` like package for meta data would be useful. Packages like `lipsum` are useful for creating MWEs and testing new classes and packages. Since the meta data varies for each class, a `blindmeta` would only be useful for established classes. As @mbork says in his comment to the question maybe you want a package that supplies macros like `\blindauthor`. Since you would still need to code all the meta commands, I just don't see the advantage.

Comment: Here's my use case: I'm preparing a style for journal.  I'll have to show it to the editorial board, and for that I'll need sample ("fake") articles.  The text can be created by `lipsum`, but I have to devise stupid names/addresses/emails/etc. myself each time...